# Inertia SSR Head Tag Causes Hydration Node Mismatch

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I'm using the VILT stack (Vue 3, Inertia 1, Laravel 10, Tailwind 3), and have enabled SSR in my app. Everything seems to work perfectly fine, until I add a Head tag, then I get `hydration node mismatch:` and `Hydration children mismatch in <div>: server rendered element contains fewer child nodes than client vdom.`

The ssr.js and app.js file are identical in terms of page formatting, including in how they define the title (`` title: title => `${title} | Projektivity`, ``). The file with the Head tag is as follows:

```
<script setup>
import {Head} from "@inertiajs/vue3";
import Tag from "@/js/Components/Project/Tag.vue";

defineProps({
    project: Object
});
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <!--suppress HtmlRequiredTitleElement -->
        <Head title="wow"/>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-4">
            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-1">
                <div class="flex flex-wrap gap-1">
                    <Tag v-for="tag in project.tags" :tag="tag" :key="tag.id"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-5">
                <h1 class="text-2xl mb-2">
                    {{ project.title }}
                </h1>
                <p>
                    {{ project.description }}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Turns out it's not the Head tag, it's the suppress comment. Any idea how to keep those comments without causing the hydration node mismatch?